# Modify decimal point and thousands separator without changing the number of decimals

Tags: php, number-formatting

I'm new to php and I'm trying to use number_format :

```
number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

As in the title, my goal is to modify decimal point and thousands separator without changing the number of decimals as below:

```
$Num=123456.789;
$Num2=number_format ($Num, [decimals as in $Num], ",", "'" );
```

My result should be:

```
$Num2="123'456,789";
```

**Edit**

I need a code for an unknown number of decimals

Comment: `$Num=123456,789;` is invalid code for php, it should be `$Num=123456.789;` There is no support for named arguments in php so you have to pass default values as can be seen into function signature.

Comment: @Flying I used a dot and not a comma assigning value to `$Num`. The code is valid Only the final output needs a comma, but it's a string!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

You will still need to specify a certain amount of fraction digits, but you can just use a high enough value and be fine. It's not like the number of digits is really arbitrary. It's tied to your [precision ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision).

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter("en_US", NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 42);
$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::GROUPING_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, "'");
$formatter->setSymbol(NumberFormatter::DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_SYMBOL, ",");
echo $formatter->format(123456.7891234); // 123'456,7891234
```

**Demo** https://3v4l.org/TCAIA

Comment: nice, only missing the formatting I guess, "123'456,789"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only a question: It works exactly as I want on a web php tester but on my pc I get error **Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found**. I'm using xampp with php 5.6.8 and I read (on the web guide) it works since version 5.3 **Any hint is appreciate**

Comment: @genespos you need to install and enable the intl extension. Check your php.ini for the line extension=intl.so or .dll and uncomment it. Restart xamp afterwards.

Comment: OOOOK! It's perfect now. Thanks again ;)

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it such a way (firstly take a look to @Gordon answer – it's much more better):

```
<?php

function extendedNumberFormat($num, $decimalSeparator, $thousandSeparator) {
    $asStr = strval($num);

    $exploded = explode('.', $asStr);
    $int = $exploded[0];
    $decimal = isset($exploded[1]) ? $exploded[1] : null;

    $result = number_format($int, 0, ".", $thousandSeparator);
    if ($decimal !== null) {
        $result .= $decimalSeparator . $decimal;
    }

    return $result;
}

echo extendedNumberFormat(123456.789, ',', "'") . "\n";
echo extendedNumberFormat(123456.7891, ',', "'") . "\n";
echo extendedNumberFormat(123456, ',', "'") . "\n";

//123'456,789
//123'456,7891
//123'456
```